# The if statmen is not working properly

Tags: php

Hi guys I have really simpy code:

```
mysql_select_db("tierra") or die(mysql_error());

$query= "SELECT DISTINCT `fecha` FROM inventarioStat WHERE `fecha` = '$timestamp'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query " . mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result); 
echo $row['fecha'];

if ($row['fecha'] == $timestamp) { break;}
else

{ 
mysql_select_db("tierra") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST["hiddenProducto"]) && count($_POST['hiddenProducto'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["hiddenProducto"] as $key => $value) {
         "TOTAL:". $total = $value;
         "<br>";
         "Value:".$value = $_POST["total"][$key];
         "<br>";
         "idItem:".$idItem = $_POST['hiddenidItem'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "Nombre:".$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
         "<br>";
         "Producto:".$producto = $_POST['hiddenProducto'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "Provedor:".$proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "undCaja:".$undCaja = $_POST['udCaja'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "sueltas:".$undCaja = $_POST['sueltas'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "formato:".$formato=$_POST['formato'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "cajas:".$cajas = $_POST['cajas'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "diferencia:".$diferencia = ($_POST['lastValue'][$key]) - $value;
         "<br>";
        $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` (fecha, localizacion, nombre, idItem, producto, proveedor, udCaja, formato, cajas, sueltas, total, diferencia) VALUES
                     ('$timestamp', '$localizacion','$nombre', '$idItem', '$producto', '$proveedor', '$undCaja', '$formato','$cajas', '$sueltas', '$value', '$diferencia')";

         mysql_query($query);
    }     

echo "Hecho!";
  }

} 


?>
```

What bother me is the following part:

```
if ($row['fecha'] == $timestamp) { break;}
```

It simply doesn't work, Im trying to avoid the duplicated dates being inserted in the database
but obviously something Im doing wrong.

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. To compare, you need `==`

Comment: `if ($row['fecha'] = $timestamp) { break;}` will almost always eval to true, therefore you will almost always `break` (unless `$timestamp` is something like `false` or `0`). use `==`, it might not fix your problem totally but using `=` is definitely wrong

Comment: try to `print_r();` both variables `$row['fecha']` and `$timestamp` to check if they are really the same..

Comment: @celeriko - not necessarily. `=` returns the value that's been assigned, so if you're assigning something false-y like 0, it will eval to false.

Comment: Where is `$timestamp` (initially) coming from?

Comment: @andrewsi ahh, your right, editing my comment now

Comment: the timestamp is coming from todays date. The idea is to stop inserting twice for the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: mysql_query is deprecated and you should look into using either ADOdb or PDO

first replace initial query with

```
$query= "SELECT COUNT(*) as fecha FROM inventarioStat WHERE `fecha` = '$timestamp'";
```

Then replace condition with

```
if (intval($row['fecha']) === 0)
{ 
mysql_select_db("tierra") or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST["hiddenProducto"]) && count($_POST['hiddenProducto'])>0) {

    foreach($_POST["hiddenProducto"] as $key => $value) {
         "TOTAL:". $total = $value;
         "<br>";
         "Value:".$value = $_POST["total"][$key];
         "<br>";
         "idItem:".$idItem = $_POST['hiddenidItem'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "Nombre:".$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
         "<br>";
         "Producto:".$producto = $_POST['hiddenProducto'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "Provedor:".$proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "undCaja:".$undCaja = $_POST['udCaja'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "sueltas:".$undCaja = $_POST['sueltas'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "formato:".$formato=$_POST['formato'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "cajas:".$cajas = $_POST['cajas'][$key];
         "<br>";
         "diferencia:".$diferencia = ($_POST['lastValue'][$key]) - $value;
         "<br>";
        $query = "INSERT INTO `inventarioStat` (fecha, localizacion, nombre, idItem, producto, proveedor, udCaja, formato, cajas, sueltas, total, diferencia) VALUES
                     ('$timestamp', '$localizacion','$nombre', '$idItem', '$producto', '$proveedor', '$undCaja', '$formato','$cajas', '$sueltas', '$value', '$diferencia')";

         mysql_query($query);
}     


echo "Hecho!";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
if ($row['fecha'] = $timestamp)
```

with

```
if ($row['fecha'] === $timestamp)  //<----- That is a strict-comparison
```

You are doing an assignment operation instead of comparison operation. You could make use of `==`  or `===`